# Is there a restriction on the folder/directory-like function?

Tags: ios

I have iPod Touch 4th generation with iOS 5.1.1. I am using the function that puts multiple icons together in a single folder/directory-like icon by moving an app icon on top of another. However, for the "Newsstand" icon, I cannot do it. Is there a restriction on the apps for this function to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Newstand app is built to be a more or less a folder of it's own. As you probably have noticed, you can't put folders inside other folders. Because this is a native app on iOS, we don't really know why they did this, but I'm confident it is indeed because of it's folder type style.